# Why the function name that starts with "do-" gets highlighted in emacs?

Tags: lisp, syntax-highlighting, emacs23

I am using [zenburn.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/zenburn.el) color-scheme in emacs 23. The function name that starts with "do-" gets highlighted, as given in the figure below --

[image]

How do I fix it? Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not observe this with Emacs 24.3 (the current development version).
The code which would have resulted in this highlighting is commented out in `lisp-mode.el`:

```
   ;; This is too general -- rms.
   ;; A user complained that he has functions whose names start with `do'
   ;; and that they get the wrong color.
   ;; ;; CL `with-' and `do-' constructs
   ;;("(\\(\\(do-\\|with-\\)\\(\\s_\\|\\w\\)*\\)" 1 font-lock-keyword-face)
```

So, what you need to do is:

```
(dolist (s (apropos-internal "lisp.*-font-lock" #'boundp))
  (set s (cl-remove-if (lambda (l)
                         (let ((re (car l)))
                           (and (stringp re)
                                (string-match re "do-something"))))
                       (symbol-value s))))
```

or just edit `lisp-mode.el`, comment out the appropriate regexp, and rebuild.